# Inserting minigames in a bigger flash stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i'm pretty new to this thing so i'm sorry if the answer is obvious. 
I made a couple of 800*640 px minigames in flash, and i was wondering if there was any way of including these in a master stage, that's 1024*768 and if it's possible to pass the value of some variables between the 2 stages, for scoring purposes.

Comment: Are you familiar with using classes? This would be pretty simple if you made each of your mini games into a class, and then just added them to the stage when you needed to. By addChilding your mini-games to the stage, you can effectively have as many "different stages" as you want.

Comment: What software are you using? It is possible to include your minigames into the 'master' stage and pass variables around. But you need to program it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting an external SWF:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

function startLoad() {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var URLreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("directory\\minigame1.swf");

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);

    loader.load(URLreq);
}

function onCompleteHandler(event:Event) {
    movieclip.addChild(event.currentTarget.content);
    movieclip.x = (stage.stageWidth - movieclip.width) / 2;
    movieclip.y = (stage.stageHeight - movieclip.height) / 2;
}

function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent) {
    var percent:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
}

startLoad();
```

---

You can passing data between **two** SWFs using `LocalConnection` :

```
// Sender - minigame1 script
var lcs:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
lcs.send("local_connection1_name", "function_name", "minigame1", 100);

// Receiver - 'master' script
var lcr:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
lcr.connect("local_connection1_name");
lcr.client = this;



function function_name(mg:String,score:int):void {
    trace(mg + ": " + score)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your suggestions were just what i was looking for.